# Comparing two strings using Parse.com data in Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, parse-platform

This is really simple but I don't know why I can't get it to work!

I want to check if the username in my Parse.com app is called User and if s/he is then a line to be printed! I don't know why this is not working at all!

Here is the code:

```
        var good = "User"

    var username = PFUser.currentUser().username

    if good = username {
        println("User is called User")
    }

    else{
        println("User is not called User")
    }
```

I get a syntax error saying: "Type '()' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'"

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double `==` instead of `=` if you want to compare something:

```
if good == username {
    println("User is called User")
}

else{
    println("User is not called User")
}
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! Also, if you know how to use parse well, can you help me with this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949865/enabling-a-button-using-data-from-parse-com-swift @Christian Woerz